# No Netflix on Firefox 77.0.1, Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu 20.04 Server/Mate Desktop

Tags: server, firefox, mate, raspberrypi, netflix

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B 8Gb with Ubuntu 20.04 Server installed and Mate desktop. I have tried to run Netflix but getting Error: 7701 1003 code.

There is no DRM (Digital Rights Management) setting in Firefox 77.0.1 made for for Ubuntu 1.0

The OpenH264 Video Codec comes with an message that "! OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc. will be installed shortly."

No Shockwave Flash extension and can't be installed.

No GNOME Shell Integration installed and seams it does not work when trying yo install the one made by Yuri Konotopov.

Any one have a solution for this?

/Marco

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this person did a very good writeup on the issue with DRM and included a fix](https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/) but it looks like you'll have to use chromium and not firefox.

Comment: Does not work. Tried that.

Comment: @MarcoOkka did you use the “ONE-LINE IT JUST WORKS” version or the full thing? what errors did you get when doing that that made it not work?

Comment: Every thing works until I open Chromium Media Edition. I can open Netflix, log in and select a show or movie but when playing episode/movie I get Error: 7701 1003 code.

When I open new tab after that I get:

Error code: RESULT_CODE_KILLED_BAD_MESSAGE

Comment: “ONE-LINE IT JUST WORKS” works on identical RPi but with 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit. Not 64-bit.

Comment: @MarcoOkka So assuming you've already seen and tried [this from Netflix about the error](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/27451) it looks like there's issues with [hardware video decode on the 64 bit version](https://www.cnx-software.com/2020/06/21/checking-out-raspberry-pi-os-64-bit-on-raspberry-pi-4-8gb-ram/) which may the the issue if Chromium Media Edition relies on that

Comment: Netflix (and HBO, Amazon Prime etc) seams not to work at all on 64-bit OS of any kind. I suspect this to be a no prio issue from the development teams working with making OS for Raspberry Pi 4. I have my other RPi 4B 8Gb running 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS with the use of the troublesome Chromium Media Edition. It is not a optimal solution. I think this issue will not be solved at this point but thank you b-rad15 for your help.